# I have a few questions about Join in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Thank you for reading it.
I'm studying cakephp and have a few questions about Join in Cakephp.
I coudn't find any appropriate answer on internet

1, What is difference between innerjoin and innerjoinwith (like leftjoin and leftjoinwith) I thought It is related with performence issue, but couldn't find any clue.

2, I can't get the exact difference between "matching" and "contain"
I know the way they retrieving data is different, but I thought the result looks same as the result of matching and matching is using innerjoin, and contain is using leftjoin.

but but I can't find what is the difference between the code below(using contain) and matching.

```
$query = $articles->find()->contain([
'Comments' => function ($q) {
return $q
->select(['body', 'author_id'])
->where(['Comments.approved' => true]);
}
]);
```

3, what is "_matchingData" in matching?
I read this description, that is
"The innerJoinWith() method works the same as matching(), that means that you can use dot notation to join deeply nested associations: Again, the only difference is that no additional columns will be added to the result set, and no _matchingData property will be set."

but I couldn't find any description about _matchingData. even in API... what it is?

you can response one of them, it is okay. please help me out

Comment: If you enable [query logging](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging), you can try different query combinations and examine the SQL generated by them, that might give you some good insight into 1 and 2. And looking at the data returned from a `matching` query should give you a clear idea of what's in `_matchingData`. A very short answer would be that if you contain a `hasMany` relationship, the records will be loaded with a separate query, while `matching` will do it with a join.

Comment: Greg Schmidt // Thank you! It is helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, What is difference between innerjoin and innerjoinwith (like leftjoin and leftjoinwith) I thought It is related with performence issue, but couldn't find any clue.

=> 
(1) here 'innerJoinWith' is a callable which will apply right/inner join 
(2) for left join 'leftJoinWith' is the callable

```
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-leftjoinwith
```

2, I can't get the exact difference between "matching" and "contain"
I know the way they retrieving data is different, but I thought the result looks same as the result of enter code here matching and matching is using innerjoin, and contain is using leftjoin.

but but I can't find what is the difference between the code below(using contain) and matching.

```
$query = $articles->find()->contain([
'Comments' => function ($q) {
return $q
->select(['body', 'author_id'])
->where(['Comments.approved' => true]);
}
]);
```

=> In short contain applies leftJoin and matching apply right/inner join to the query. 
please read this first line on this link https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith

3, what is "_matchingData" in matching?
I read this description, that is
"The `innerJoinWith()` method works the same as matching(), that means that you can use dot notation to join deeply nested associations: Again, the only difference is that no additional columns will be added to the result set, and no `_matchingData` property will be set."

but I couldn't find any description about _matchingData. even in API... what it is?

=> `_matchingData()` is an entity property created when matching() is used. It contains data which is selected matching

```
$query = $articles->find(); 
$query = $query->matching('Comments', function($q){
            $q->select(['Comments.body', 'Comments.author_id']);
            $q->where(['Comments.is_approved' => 1]);
        return $q;
});
```

Above query will have _matchingData property contained with Comments.body, Comments.author_id

Comment: Thank you for answering to my questions.
You saved me!
I just want to check if "callable" which you commented at question number 1 is same as the link below.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Thank you for your answer again!

Comment: Yes callable / callbacks you can pass function as an argument